# Pic microcontroller relay switching of 1 HP single phase motor

Tags: logic-gates

The situation is I am using pic microcontroller for power supply I am using 230 to 12 v stepdown transformer + 1000 uf 25 v capacitor + lm7805 + 10 uf 25 v capacitor from and these two positive and negative terminals I use as +5v and gnd for pic microcontroller I also applied decoupling capacitor (104 ceramic)and for 12 coil of relay I took +12 v from 1000 uf  capacitor directly and ground is connected to capacitor's negative terminal ! When I am switching motor on and of it resets my system and all program getting start again execution ! Please tell me your suggestions and ask if you didn't get question!

Comment: Too much hand waving.  Show a schematic.

Comment: @user103110 That's not a schematic.

Comment: yes it is not schemetic bcoz i also want to know is it any pcb designing faults ? plz just study pcb and help

Comment: Post the schematic anyway.  It helps to have the circuit that goes with the layout.

Comment: The layout can be useful to see, but we're not going to reverse engineer it to figure out the circuit.  It's your job to provide a proper schematic.

Answer (score 2):

The verbal description of your setup is not clear, but the issue is probably around how the relay is driven.  Possible problems:

Low side NPN without base resistor.

No flyback catch diode.

12 V supply doesn't have enough power to drive the relay.

Bad grounding.  Relay coil current return messing up processor voltages.

It also sounds like you are overdriving the relay.  12 VAC is going to make more than 12 V DC.

Comment: olin sir can you tell me how can i reve this noise which relay cause! @Owlin Lathrop

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of factors not provided.  But suppose for a moment that the motor current is 10A.  Suppose the reset pin current is 0.1 mA.  The motor trace loop creates a magnetic field from a current 80-100 dB higher (plus surges) than the reset pin current.  You are trying to provide something in the order of 80 dB separation between the motor trace loop field and the reset pin trace loop.  That is very hard to do.  From the picture above there is no sign of a ground plane. It looks like single layer copper.  Ground in places looks like a little track maybe 20 mil wide.  The coupling/isolation between the motor magnetic field and the reset magnetic field depends on the area of the loop of the respective currents.  A solid ground plane would help.  Minimizing the area from reset pin to ground trace loop with a bypass would help.  Minimizing the area of the motor current loop would help. But you could still have trouble if there is a high ratio of the currents. For this kind of application, you might need a ground fence and a can over the sensitive circuit. If all this sounds complicated, getting 80 dB EMI isolation in a layout is complicated and requires very careful layout.

Comment: I had run this exact system on general purpose PCB at that time it was running superb but in PCB it causes resets

Answer (score 0):

You NEED to post a schematic. It's impossible to see what else might be going on with this circuit.

10pF as shown in your overlay layer across the uC supply (if that is really what it is) is NOT sufficient. 100nF to 1uF would be more appropriate.

You have serpentine traces running to the microcontroller supply and you are using pretty much the cheapest and worst relays possible for the switching so you can expect large coupling between the motor transients and the microcontroller. They should actually be rated to switch a 1HP **motor load** and have high coil-contact breakdown ratings.

I don't have a big problem with the relay current return layout, but it could be a bit better.

It is possible to make this kind of circuit reliable on a single-sided board for very low cost, but it requires a lot more effort than it would to use high quality parts, double-sided board with ground pour and so on. Even if you patch this one so it seems to work, you may find that it misbehaves as the relay contacts wear.

Comment: As u said I attached parallel extra ceramic 104 cap and pic stopped resetting but for 20 seconds and again I attached another same cap parallel now it worked fine for 40 second what is Maximum value I can use for decoupling capacitor